# Image max-height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have got a tiny problem, im creating a website and i want to give an image a max-height. The image may only have the same height of another div.

You can check the layout here: http://bit.ly/1OAGsLR
Its about the 1920x1080 image, and i needs to be the same height as the div with class box left to it. If right the image should scale well.

But im trying all i know but i dont get it working, can someone get this working with CSS or do i need to use Javascript for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Uhm dude, that looks like its working.

Comment: Wouldn't this image be out of proportion if that div is taller and you matching the height?

Comment: Am I the only one who doesn't get it ?

Comment: @Katherina Nope it isnt working, the image has a 359px height and the leftbox a 339px height.

Comment: @Katherina You're certainly not alone. The image fills its box perfectly. It has a max-width and a max-height set and there a padding to the box. I am confused, this is behaving as expected.

Comment: @somethinghere The image needs to have the same height as the box with the information. So the bottom of the image needs to be lined out with the bottom of the button

Comment: @Chiel I see now what you are trying to do, but it won't work simply because of how inherited heights work. If any of your boxes is auto-sizing itself, then it will fail. Let me see if theres a solution that might get it to work but it won't be pretty :)

Answer (score 0):

Your image is looking the way you want when the screen width is at or above 1400px.  You should consider using css media queries to move or adjust the image at different screen widths. Your layout could easily be handled using a css framework like [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) or [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) which would take care of css media query breakpoints for you.

If you are intentionally trying to not use a css framework, I'd check out this [css media queries tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your container div wider.
Your container is 1200px wide, and your boxes are 560 + 40 padding wide each.
That means that the max width of you image is 560px. 
Now to conserve it's aspect ratio of 16:9, the max height of the image is 560 / 16 * 9 = 315 pixels.

Comment: box-sizing: border-box.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, your main problem is that heights don't like to be defined this way. I have a solution for you that will 'solve' this issue, but its not very pretty and you might want to look into doing this with javascript anyhow. Below is a very rough example mockup.

```css
body > div {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
body > div > div {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
}
body > div > img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  max-width: 50%;
  /* make sure to fall back to 80% so theres at least some gutter for older browsers */
  max-height: 80%;
  /* use calc to make the image the height of the relative parent minus padding */
  max-height: calc(100% - 40px);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>Push<br />Push<br />Push<br />Push<br />Push<br /></div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
</div>
```

In short, this will place your image to the right of your box, give it a `max-height` (because positioning can do that) and a `max-width` (so smaller screen sizes don't freak out).

Now you could easily translate this a more general system where `.box + .box`get a absolute position, or you could define a class for the box that has to push content and add that to the first box, making all other boxes absolute.

Comment: Seems legit, but yeah. Its kinda not very pretty. So i just used a max-height: 300px; on the image seems most legit in most browser.

Comment: @Chiel I know that solves your issue, but like so many other answers here, its not a solution that scales very well. It works here because your content has that height at the widest position, but if you ever add content, it will stop working. Its either this or JavaScript I'd say. Also 'not very pretty' but it scales well to any screen size, its just not very much page-flowy, but tbh thats not as important at the point your start using CSS.

Comment: I think im going to use some javascript then, i just put the height of the .box in a variabel and change the image max-height to that var right? @somethinghere

Comment: I'de say keep your image height at mac-height: 100% and just give the outer box the same innerHeight as your other box, that way the image still scales itself (otherwise you might as well not use the box at all).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using JS, im using the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeheight(){
        var Height = document.getElementById('box').clientHeight;
        document.getElementById('imagebox').style.height = Height+'px';
    }
</script>
```